# Qt open image from file - how to know image size

Tags: c++, image, file, qt

I am getting image file with QFileDialog. Image can be in different standard image file extensions. How can I get image size (width and height)?

Comment: QImage has `width()` and `height()` methods. Create a QImage from the file and call them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a QPixmap from retrieved file name and call [QPixmap::size()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#size)

Answer (score 19):

If you only need the size of the image, but not the image itself, it is better to use the QImageReader. As described in the [wiki](http://wiki.qt.io/Loading_Large_Images), not all image data is loaded. This procedure should be much faster:

```
QImageReader reader("image.png");
QSize sizeOfImage = reader.size();
int height = sizeOfImage.height();
int width = sizeOfImage.width();
```